# gnuplot tikz terminal missing

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot, tikz

I installed gnuplot 5.4. To use tikz I follow  [this link](http://www.gnuplotting.org/installing-the-tikz-terminal/)

but symbolic link is broken.I can't use tikz as terminal. I have tried several times without success.
system requirements :
ubuntu 22.10
lua 5.2.4
texlive 2022
How to make the symbolic link functional?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

lua must be present when gnuplot is built. In particular the configuration script must be able to find the file "lua.h", which may require installation of a lua development package.  Installing lua or lua-devel afterwards is too late for inclusion of luz/tikz support in the gnuplot executable.

Comment: removing gnuplot  will  resolve the problem?

Comment: Rebuilding from source, or installing a different executable that was built with lua support.

Comment: I'll remove gnuplot, rebuild and hope that works!

Comment: Could you please give me details. I can't get symlink work. How to remove, reinstall correctly gnuplot including installation.

Comment: No answer possible unless you show what you have done and what happened.  What output did you get from "./configure"?   Please say what operating system you are using and what you tried to install.

Comment: Thank you, no need. I remove broken symlink, gnuplot work now with tikz.